# Is NSLog have any affect on application performance?

Tags: ios, performance, nslog

Hi i have enormous calculation going on in my application as i have `NSLog` statement called at-lest 2000 times its a Big application of 11 MB. I am thinking to Remove this From my application so as to improve the performance. M i thinking in a right way ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, while the debugger is running and issuing NSLog calls, performance can be severely affected. Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461338/iphone-ipad-does-having-many-nslog-calls-affect-app-preformance-or-memory) question.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't matter as it is serialized: "Output from NSLogv is serialized, in that only one thread in a process can be doing the writing/logging described above at a time. All attempts at writing/logging a message complete before the next thread can begin its attempts."

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog

Comment: well its good for development purpose but there is no use in the running application on Device , so its better i commnet out Major NSLog .